# Code igniter code for connect Remote Mysql DB from Localhost

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i am try to access all remote server mysql data from my localhost. but i don't know how to connect remote database server my  local database.
and my local database connection code is

```
$db['on_app']['hostname'] = 'host ip address';
$db['on_app']['username'] = 'host username';
$db['on_app']['password'] = 'host password';
$db['on_app']['database'] = 'host db name';
$db['on_app']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql'`enter code here`;
$db['on_app']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['on_app']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['on_app']['db_debug'] = FALSE;

$db['on_app']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['on_app']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['on_app']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['on_app']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['on_app']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['on_app']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['on_app']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Have you confirmed if you are allowed to connect directly to that remote MySQL server? (in many cases the answer is no for security reasons) If yes, have you obtained its connection details (IP address / host name / port number / etc.)? If yes, then just substitute the above into your code. Your code actually guides you what you need to be able to connect to your remote server.

Answer (score 1):

In the database.php file under the application->config folder edit the default connection with your details

```
$db['default'] = array(
'dsn'   => '',
'hostname' => 'your.server.ip.address',
'username' => 'yourserverusername',
'password' => 'your_db_password',
'database' => 'your_db_name',
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

you will have to create a user on your server and open the database to either all ips or whichever ips you wish

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me.

- Open PHPMyAdmin in the Remote DB Server
- Create a user with **all privilages**. Remember to **set host to %**.
- Edit mysqld.cnf and set "bind-address = 0.0.0.0" (may be 
  /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf).
- Restart MySQL.